# Header background image repeats / tile after zoom out

Tags: css

I have here a header with background image that occupies the upper part of my website. On my stylesheet, the `background-repeat` is set to `no-repeat` but after I zoom out the page to 80%, it repeats. Is there any way to control it through css?

Please try the snippet below on full-page then try to zoom-out to 80%
My Screen Resolution: 1920x1080

```css
.header-banner{
    width: 100%;
    height:340px;
    min-height:340px;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background:url('https://i.ibb.co/0jnNWwH/slots-banner-1.jpg') rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) ;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
  }
  .header-banner h1 {
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header-banner">
  <div class="form-group text-center">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background` property replaces *all* `background-*` properties. Either move this line before all of your other `background-*` properties, or use `background-image` and `background-color`.

```css
.header-banner{
    width: 100%;
    height:340px;
    min-height:340px;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/0jnNWwH/slots-banner-1.jpg');
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
  }
  .header-banner h1 {
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header-banner">
  <div class="form-group text-center">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks!